# Hover on overflow text is jumping

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this situation where the mouse hover shows the complete text but it's jumping on hover.

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/xeongtha/**

```css
    img {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .modal__grey--name {
      width: 105px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 1.1;
    }
    .modal__grey--name:hover {
      overflow: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E %3Cg fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E %3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='%23F8F8F8'/%3E %3Cpath fill='%23DDD' fill-rule='nonzero' d='M100 50c0-27.57-22.43-50-50-50S0 22.43 0 50c0 14.562 6.262 27.687 16.23 36.833l-.048.042 1.622 1.367c.105.089.22.162.325.249.862.714 1.755 1.393 2.664 2.049.294.213.589.425.889.633.97.669 1.967 1.303 2.985 1.905.222.131.446.258.67.386 1.114.634 2.252 1.232 3.418 1.781.085.04.172.077.258.117 3.798 1.765 7.852 3.062 12.092 3.827l.335.06c1.316.227 2.647.41 3.995.531.163.015.327.024.492.038 1.342.111 2.698.182 4.073.182 1.362 0 2.705-.07 4.04-.178.17-.015.338-.024.507-.038 1.337-.122 2.657-.299 3.96-.522.113-.02.228-.04.34-.062 4.177-.75 8.173-2.016 11.922-3.736.138-.064.278-.124.416-.19 1.122-.527 2.219-1.096 3.293-1.701.267-.151.533-.304.798-.46.979-.577 1.94-1.178 2.875-1.818.336-.23.665-.471.998-.711.798-.575 1.582-1.168 2.344-1.788.169-.136.35-.254.516-.394l1.664-1.39-.05-.041C93.679 77.82 100 64.636 100 50zM3.636 50C3.636 24.435 24.435 3.636 50 3.636c25.565 0 46.364 20.799 46.364 46.364 0 13.776-6.046 26.162-15.617 34.66-.534-.37-1.072-.7-1.623-.976l-15.395-7.697c-1.382-.69-2.24-2.08-2.24-3.623v-5.377c.356-.44.733-.938 1.122-1.485 1.993-2.815 3.59-5.946 4.756-9.315 2.304-1.094 3.791-3.389 3.791-5.98v-6.445c0-1.577-.578-3.106-1.613-4.307v-8.486c.095-.944.43-6.269-3.423-10.662-3.351-3.825-8.775-5.762-16.122-5.762-7.347 0-12.77 1.937-16.122 5.76-3.853 4.393-3.518 9.719-3.423 10.662v8.486c-1.033 1.202-1.613 2.73-1.613 4.307v6.445c0 2.002.898 3.87 2.436 5.13 1.473 5.769 4.504 10.136 5.624 11.616v5.262c0 1.483-.81 2.847-2.113 3.56l-14.376 7.842c-.458.249-.913.54-1.368.865C9.593 75.985 3.636 63.676 3.636 50zm73.562 37.513c-.636.462-1.283.909-1.94 1.336-.302.196-.602.393-.909.584-.858.53-1.73 1.036-2.622 1.509-.196.103-.394.202-.592.303-2.048 1.05-4.166 1.951-6.342 2.684-.077.026-.153.053-.231.078-1.14.378-2.295.715-3.462 1.004l-.01.002c-1.18.29-2.372.532-3.572.73l-.098.019c-1.13.183-2.267.316-3.41.416-.2.018-.403.031-.606.046-1.13.085-2.264.14-3.404.14-1.153 0-2.302-.057-3.445-.142-.199-.015-.397-.027-.593-.046-1.153-.101-2.3-.238-3.437-.423l-.152-.028c-2.404-.401-4.77-.992-7.073-1.765-.07-.024-.144-.05-.215-.073-1.143-.389-2.274-.82-3.385-1.296l-.024-.011c-1.05-.453-2.081-.955-3.1-1.484-.132-.069-.267-.134-.398-.205-.929-.496-1.838-1.033-2.734-1.593-.266-.167-.53-.336-.791-.507-.826-.54-1.64-1.102-2.433-1.696-.082-.062-.16-.128-.242-.19l.175-.098 14.376-7.842c2.473-1.349 4.01-3.936 4.01-6.752l-.003-6.55-.418-.505c-.04-.045-3.97-4.827-5.456-11.302l-.166-.72-.62-.401c-.874-.566-1.398-1.511-1.398-2.531v-6.446c0-.845.358-1.633 1.013-2.223l.6-.542V30.865l-.016-.238c-.006-.043-.542-4.416 2.538-7.927 2.629-2.996 7.134-4.518 13.387-4.518 6.23 0 10.72 1.509 13.356 4.483 3.077 3.475 2.573 7.93 2.57 7.966l-.017 10.365.6.542c.653.59 1.013 1.378 1.013 2.224v6.445c0 1.297-.882 2.473-2.147 2.864l-.904.278-.291.9c-1.073 3.333-2.6 6.411-4.538 9.15-.477.672-.94 1.268-1.338 1.725l-.451.514v6.726c0 2.93 1.629 5.567 4.25 6.876l15.395 7.696c.098.05.195.1.291.151-.194.148-.394.284-.59.426z'/%3E %3C/g%3E %3C/svg%3E" class="dropdown__static--profile"> 
      <span class="modal__grey--name">This is a long text that needs to be cut</span>
      <span class="checkmark" style="padding-left: 4px;"></span>
    </label>
```

Comment: Adding `vertical-align: top;` for `.modal__grey--name` should also be able to fix the issue, if you don’t want to go flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Remove *line-height: 1.1;* and add *vertical-align: middle;*

```
img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.modal__grey--name {
  width: 105px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal__grey--name:hover {
  overflow: inherit;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7mfagb9/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can make your label a flexbox and it won't jump anymore:

```
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used the other solution. This works as well. Upvoted :)